# How to insert MathML Equation in Word, using Open XML SDK?

Tags: c#, latex, openxml-sdk, mathml, omml

I have some LaTeX code, that need to be converted into MathML, that can then be inserted in Word with Open XML SDK.

My problem is everything basically... I have tried to use the MML2OMML.XSL that Microsoft provide, but Open XML SDK cant insert the MathML as an equation. When i copy the OMML into word as plain text it just inserts the OMML text, but when i try to copy the Presentation MathML as plain text, into word, it makes an equation field an sets everything up as i want it. And when i try to insert it with Open XML SDK, it doesnt work at all.

All in all, i need to convert LaTeX code into some kind of MathML, that can then be inserted in a Word document, which is created every time i execute the code, with Open XML SDK. Hope it makes sense!
I use C#, AvaloniaUI and CommunityToolKit
Thanks in advance :)